# image positioning both vertically and horizontaly

Tags: graphics, positioning

Hi I have 4 images where images: image1.eps, image2.eps, image3.eps are the same size, and image4.eps which is smaller.
I put all the images in the document in following way:

```
\begin{figure}[pt]
\centerline{
\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth,scale=1.0]{image1.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth,scale=1.0]{image2.eps}
}
\centerline{
\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth,scale=1.0]{image3.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth,scale=1.0]{image4.eps}
}
\caption[Capt]
{Description}
\label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}
```

The effect is as below:

[image]

But I expected following:

[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the images in a tabular, for instance like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}{@{}>{\hfill}m{0.5\textwidth}<{\hfill\null}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[pt]
\noindent\begin{tabular}{MM}
\rule{5cm}{4cm} & \rule{5cm}{4cm} \\\\[.5ex]
\rule{5cm}{4cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm}
\end{tabular}
\caption[Capt]
{Description}
\label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]